# generating random int input from -100 to 100

Tags: c++, c++11, math

I want to generate random numbers between -100 to 100 however i am not sure which of these will generate the right numbers
`rand()%201  - 100;` or `rand()%200  - 100;`

Comment: Start by determining what the maximum and minimum possible value `rand() % 200` and `rand() % 201` can each produce. Then do `-100` to each and see what ranges you are left with.

Comment: You may want to consider the more modern C++ random number facilities (which are also less confusing to use), [`std::uniform_int_distribution `](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: This should be easy for you to test for yourself

Comment: What happened in the edit?

Comment: *Please* don't use `rand()` in new code in 2020. Please use the new modern [random facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) we've had available for the past 9 years (since C++11). Also; unless 201 divides evenly into the maximum output of your generator, your `%201` introduces bias into your results.

Answer (score 1):

The first one, `rand()%201 - 100`.

The second one will never hit positive 100, as rand()%200 will never be 200.

Comment: I didn't have enough coffee before posting, please ignore my prior comment. I realized what I'd said as soon as I submitted the comment.